# How to properly run docker with Makefile

Tags: linux, unix, docker, makefile

I have a make file:

```
APP_NAME=sgy-core-bdd/codeception

build: ## Build the container
    docker build -t $(APP_NAME) .

run:
    docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash -i -t -v $(pwd):/app $(APP_NAME)
```

when i do `make run` i get this error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/app', needed by `run'.  Stop.
```

How do I resolve this error

Comment: Nothing in your `Makefile` shows a dependency on `/app`. Voting to close as unreproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recipe lines must be indented with a real TAB character.  In your example, it's likely that line is not indented with a TAB.

That means that this line:

```
docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash -i -t -v $(pwd):/app $(APP_NAME)
```

is treated as a make rule, not a recipe, which is the equivalent of writing:

```
docker: /app $(APP_NAME)
run: /app $(APP_NAME)
--entrypoint: /app $(APP_NAME)
/bin/bash: /app $(APP_NAME)
-i: /app $(APP_NAME)
-t: /app $(APP_NAME)
-v: /app $(APP_NAME)
$(pwd): /app $(APP_NAME)
```

So when you use `make run`, it wants to build the prerequisites `/app` and `$(APP_NAME)`.