# docker with makefile volume mounts

Tags: docker, makefile

So recently came across this weird case where I am trying to access file in my local dir into my container.
When I run the following command on terminal it runs fine and shows the expected list of file

```
docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/mnt/data -w /mnt/data-sink artprod.dev.abc.com/org/cli ls
```

But when I try to run this  via makefile it shows nothing,(I run make in the same path where I run the docker cmd in the previous step)

```
docker-publish: build
    echo "Publishing $(APP_NAME) snapshot $(VERSION)"
    docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/mnt/data -w /mnt/data-sink artprod.dev.abc.com/org/cli ls
```

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823518/how-to-properly-run-docker-with-makefile

Comment: What do you mean it "shows nothing"?  Does make show the commands it's running?  Please show the command you typed and the output you got, cut and pasted in with formatting (not a screenshot etc.)

Comment: @sanchith Yes I had seen that earlier. My make file is tab indented. Also I don't get any make errors. In fact I don't get any errors. it's the `ls` prints different results when run with make and when run individually on terminal.  When I say different results i mean one with make doesn't list any files so empty results and one run directly on the the terminal returns list of files

Comment: `$(pwd)` in a Makefile expands the Make variable `pwd`; it doesn't do shell interpolation.  Consider `$$(pwd)` to escape the dollar sign so it gets passed to the shell instead.

Comment: thanks for the tip @DavidMaze that was indeed the issue.... some how $$(pwd) didnt do the magic but $(shell pwd) worked. thanks

Answer (score 2):

$(shell pwd) worked simply $(pwd) in make didnt do the shell interpolation.